# Marriage Reception (Walimah)

Tags: nikah, fiqh, sunnah

Can we have marriage reception (Walimah) on the third day after the Nikkah. Because we already planned and communicated to  the bride`s family.
But I heard that Walimah will be invalid on the third day. Can you clarify the time of the walimah? Will it be considered valid or just a food feast?

Comment: Are you asking for an Islamic answer to the question? If not this is not a proper question for this site because questions on cultures of muslim society irrelevant to the study of Islam are considered off-topic.

Comment: Yes, i am askign about Islamic Law perspective

Answer (score 2):

**In order to elucidate the issue, you ought to pay attention that marriage reception or  Walimah (banquet ) is not a Wajib (mandatory) act, haply this is solely a Mustahab (recommended) deed as a Sunnah act. Hence you ought not to see it as a mandatory act.**

On the whole, the definition of Walimah is:

> A party which consists of at least ten people. (Mahmud Abdul Rahman,
>   Mo’jam al Mostalahat)
>
> (محمود عبد الرحمان‏، معجم المصطلحات و الألفاظ الفقهیة، ج ‏3، ص 504.)

Note: to see more matter regarding Walimah, you can refer to the source below.

---

**Source**:

[islamquest.net](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa16371)

Answer (score 1):

Well the wedding meal (walimah) is a Sunna which our Messenger (peace be upon him) never skipped!

And about the time for it: there are differences between scholars, whether it can be done when the contract of marriage ('Aqd an-nikah) is written, or afterwards or even after fulfilling the marriage or afterwards or between the writing of contract until the consummation of the marriage!

> قال الحافظ ابن حجر : "وَقَدْ اِخْتَلَفَ السَّلَف فِي وَقْتهَا ، هَلْ هُوَ عِنْد الْعَقْد ، أَوْ عَقِبه ، أَوْ عِنْد الدُّخُول ، أَوْ عَقِبه ، أَوْ مُوَسَّع مِنْ اِبْتِدَاء الْعَقْد إِلَى اِنْتِهَاء الدُّخُول ، عَلَى أَقْوَال" انتهى .

But from ahadith one could conclude that our Messenger (peace be upon him) had chosen to do it after consummation of the marriage (see for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/70/95)).

And on the other hand there's no valid reference stating a limitation or a time when it has to be done, so you are free to do it at the time you like, but you should take care about local customs if there are any!

See also the following [fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/131252) (English) and [Khotba-text](http://www.alminbar.net/alkhutab/khutbaa.asp?mediaURL=7838) (Arabic)

And Allah knows best!